# fullcalendar won't display json feed using eventSource

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I'm working with fullcalendar for the first time. it seemed straight forward at first but then problems. Ok I am trying to use eventSource to load multiple sources. It loads all the google calendar sources no problem but the json feed is not being displayed. I'm wondering if its because I'm using a static json file to test or maybe I left out something, or is the json formatted wrong. Do I need to code a json feed in java to test (working with java)? These are the things I've looked at and I've looked at the other links regarding fullcalendar and json and none helped. If someone could give me a little help it would greatly appreciated.

feed.json

```
{
            "events":
    [
        {
                "id": "0",
                "title": "Business Lunch",
                "start": "2015-09-03T13:00:00",
                "end": "2015-09-03T14:00:00",
                "constraint": "businessHours"
        },
        {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "Conference",
                "start": "2015-09-18",
                "end": "2015-09-19",
                "constraint": "businessHours"
        },
        {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "Party",
                "start": "2015-09-29T20:00:00",
                "end": "2015-09-29T24:00:00",
                "constraint": "businessHours"
        }

    ]
}
```

code sample

```
eventSources: [

    // your event source
    //feed source
    {
        url: '/hairzone/feed.json',
        type: 'GET', //GET or POST
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            custom_param1: 'something',
            custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option

    },

    // any other sources...
    {
        googleCalendarId: 'some calendar id',
        color: 'pink',   // an option!
        textColor: 'black', // an option!
        //rendering: 'background'
        overlay:false
    },

    // any other sources...
    {
        googleCalendarId: 'some calendar id',
        color: 'blue',   // an option!
        textColor: 'black', // an option!
        rendering: 'background',
        overlay:false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It seems that the feed is not formatted properly for fullcalendar. It just need everything starting with the brackets. Doesn't matter if its a static file or generated feed.

```
[
    {
            "id": "0",
            "title": "Business Lunch",
            "start": "2015-09-03T13:00:00",
            "end": "2015-09-03T14:00:00",
            "constraint": "businessHours"
    },
    {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Conference",
            "start": "2015-09-18",
            "end": "2015-09-19",
            "constraint": "businessHours"
    },
    {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Party",
            "start": "2015-09-29T20:00:00",
            "end": "2015-09-29T24:00:00",
            "constraint": "businessHours"
    }

]
```

Comment: This link helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798958/jquery-full-calendar-json-event-source-syntax