# Adding to an Array to produce formatted jSON Data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to produce a jSON array like answer #2 on this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798958/jquery-full-calendar-json-event-source-syntax)

```
    [
  {
    "title": "Ceramics",
    "id": "821",
    "start": "2014-11-13 09:00:00",
    "end": "2014-11-13 10:30:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Zippy",
    "id": "822",
    "start": "2014-11-13 10:00:00",
    "end": "2014-11-13 11:30:00"
  }
]
```

I am getting the UK & Wales Bank Holidays' from an API and I am getting users' holidays from my DB Selection...

All data is correct, But at the present moment I'm only getting 1 item from the $holidays array.

I need the bank holidays and holidays all to return in the same form as the jSON Document linked above.

My code is as follows :

```
    $holidays = DB::table('holiday_requests')
        ->where('status', 'accepted')
        ->join('users', 'users.user_id', '=', 'holiday_requests.user_id')
        ->select('users.user_firstname', 'users.user_surname', 'holiday_requests.holiday_request_date_from', 'holiday_requests.holiday_request_date_to', 'holiday_requests.holiday_request_id')
        ->get();

    $bank_holidays = array();
    $holidays_array = array();

    // Get Bank Holiday jSon From External Source...
    $uri = 'https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json';

    // Get the Results and return as a JSON Object
    $json_data = @file_get_contents($uri);

    // Decode The JSON Object
    $json_output = json_decode($json_data);

    $england_wales = "england-and-wales";

    if ($json_output)
    {
        foreach($json_output->$england_wales->events as $event)
        {
            $bank_holidays['title'] = $event->title;
            $bank_holidays['start'] = $event->date;
            $bank_holidays['end'] = $event->date;
        }
    }

    foreach($holidays as $holiday)
    {
        $holidays_array['title'] = $holiday->user_firstname;
        $holidays_array['title'].= " ";
        $holidays_array['title'].= $holiday->user_surname;
        $holidays_array['title'].= " - ";
        $holidays_array['title'].= "Holiday";
        $holidays_array['id'] = $holiday->holiday_request_id;
        $holidays_array['start'] = $holiday->holiday_request_date_from;
        $holidays_array['end'] = $holiday->holiday_request_date_to;
    }

    return Response::json(array($bank_holidays));
```

Its worth mentioning I am using Laravel, However this is more of a specific PHP and Array type question.

Thanks

Comment: looks like you got a little typo, `foreach($holidays as $holiday)` should probably be `foreach($bank_holidays as $holiday)`

Comment: also, maybe you meant to return `$holidays_array` instead of `$bank_holidays` ... you're creating the `$holidays_array` array and not doing anythign with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the array each time through the loops.  You need a multidimensional array.  Something like this:

```
foreach($json_output->$england_wales->events as $event)
{
    $bank_holidays[] = array('title' => $event->title,
                             'start' => $event->date,
                             'end'   => $event->date);
}
```

Then do the same for the next loop, however, you are creating `$bank_holidays` and `$holidays_array` but only returning `$bank_holidays`.  You may want to merge them or just create the same array in both loops.