# generate json event for full calendar from sql query

Tags: json, fullcalendar, metamug

I'm using item request to retrieve attendance information for a student using his/her student id.

```
<Request method="GET" item="true">
    <Query>
     select subject, in_time, out_time 
     from tbl_attendance where student_id = $id
    </Query>   
</Request>
```

Currently I'm getting json in below format for this request.

https://api.metamug.com/tinkertech/v1.0/attendance/1000

```
[
    {
        "out_time": "2017-03-18 12:00:01.0",
        "in_time": "2017-03-18 12:00:01.0",
        "subject": "Maths"
    },
    {
        "out_time": "2017-03-19 13:00:01.0",
        "in_time": "2017-03-18 12:00:01.0",
        "subject": "Bio"
    }

]
```

I'm trying to generate event json as per this answer
[Jquery Full Calendar json event source syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798958/jquery-full-calendar-json-event-source-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the SQL in your resource xml as follows:

```
    <Query>
       SELECT subject AS title, DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%Y-%m-%dT%T') AS start,
          DATE_FORMAT(out_time,'%Y-%m-%dT%T') AS end 
             FROM tbl_attendance WHERE student_id=$id
    </Query>
```

Note that the 'AS' keyword is used to name the JSON key in your response. This should transform your above JSON response into something like this:

```
[
    {
        "end": "2017-03-18 12:00:01",
        "start": "2017-03-18 12:00:01",
        "title": "Maths"
    },
    {
        "end": "2017-03-19 13:00:01",
        "start": "2017-03-18 12:00:01",
        "title": "Bio"
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm getting T in the json, but it works now. e.g. "2017-03-19T13:00:01"